# Results no good when summing total differential about transport of a vector

Tags: numerical-methods, differential

I think that my issue could be solved on this forum because this is about mathematic and numerical
problems. If you think this is not the right place, please let me know.

I have coded an application which reproduces the transport of a vector along a geodesic (actually called
"great circle" because I consider a spherical surface).

You can use it on the following link :

[transport animation][1]

The following image represents the starting scene of animation :

[image: Starting scene of animation]

Once image is loaded, you can click on it to see the full window, change parameters on the right-top menu like
angles of rotation along Ox and Oz axis, and starting vector coordinates (theta and phi components).

Finally, you can launch animation by clicking on "Start" button.

The yellow circle is the geodesic.

The shadow plane represents the tangent plane of the current point of geodesic (it is always face to the user. theta and phi basis vectors are 
represented by pink vectors).

You can see that turquoise vector is the initial vector and the green one is the transported vector (its angle with
yellow geodesic is always the same).

This transport makes change the coordinates of green vector in local tangent plane (i.e shadow window) : these changes are ruled by computing
the total differential of each vector component (the formula are located at the top-left window).

As you can see in output results called "Total differential for current Interation", I compute the value of $\text{D}v^{\theta}$ and $\text{D}v^{\varphi}$ between
2 consecutive iterations on the yellow great circle.

Here's below a figure representing the current value of tangent plane origin ($\theta,\varphi$) when I browse along the geodesic :

[image: Longitude and latitude]

Here's below the figure representing the value of total differential for each iteration, (actually, like I said above, I compute the total differential between 2 consecutive iterations), up to the end of animation that I have performed by clicking on "Pause" button.

[image: total differential for current iteration]

On the figure above, These total differentials ($\text{D}v^{\theta}$,$\text{D}v^{\varphi}$) are changing in a cyclic way, and mostly, $\text{D}v^{\theta}$ and $\text{D}v^{\varphi}$ are very closed to zero value (with order of 10^-2 for the 
amplitude on the figure above) : that are the expected values.

So everything seems to be good except one thing : When I want to do the summation of all previous total differential (for each iteration like above), I don't get a cyclic
change and the values for both $\text{D}v^{\theta}$ and $\text{D}v^{\varphi}$ are increasing as and when animation is running.

Here's below the figure illustrating this increase :

[image: integrated total differential with summation]

If I do the summation of all terms corresponding each one to only one iteration, I compute :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\text{D}v^{\theta})_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (v^{\theta})_{i+1} - (v^{\theta})_{i} - (v^{\varphi})_i\, \text{sin}\theta_{i} \text{cos}\theta_{i} (\varphi_{i+1}-\varphi_i)
$$

$\implies$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\text{D}v^{\theta})_i = (v^{\theta})_{n+1} - (v^{\theta})_{1} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} v^{\varphi}_i\, \text{sin}\theta_{i} \text{cos}\theta_{i} (\varphi_{i+1}-\varphi_i)$$

and the same king of computing for : $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\text{D}v^{\varphi})_i$$

My main isue is that I don't understand why the values of integrated total differential are increasing : If I let the animation during a long time, the values can be really
different from zero (one excepts always the values to be closed to zero for this integrated total differential, like for only one iteration).

From a mathematic point of view, the total differential (for one interation or by summing) is always equal to zero but here, this is a numerical simulation, so I except values closed to zero, not strictly null.

Maybe, a little error is accumulated at each rotation. However, I thought that error would be itself compensated when I am in positive latitude and negative case (for example or on another criterion), so the summation should be cyclic and not increasing.

If someone could help me to fix this issue, this would be kind.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

@Professor Vector

Here is the result when I take the half of step used in all above figures : this figure represents the summation of total differential :

[image: integrated total differential with summation and Half step (**0.005 instead of 0.01**)]

As you can see, the cumulated error is smaller. If I compare the area of **"1000"-th iteration** (which corresponds to **"500"-th** iteration for initial step (I mean the step used in all above figures, i.e **step=0.01**), the value is about **0.5e-4** with half step whereas the same area for initial step is **2e-4**. So I have roughly about a factor 4x between the 2 cases.

Is there a way to prevent this increasing ? I think I could make decrease the error by taking again a smaller step but in this case, animation is very very ... slow.

Comment: Are you doing those calculations with float or double (32 or 64 bit floating point numbers)?

Comment: -@Professor Vector From what I have seen, all numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point numbers, so I think all computations are done in double precision.

Comment: Then, the error would be surprisingly big, indeed. In single precision, I would expect that after a few thousand steps, but not in double precision.

Comment: I think it's because you're summing, not integrating, it's like calculating an integral with the trapezoidal rule. How does the error change if you half the step size?

Comment: -@Professor Vector you can see the results in my **UPDATE 1** above. Regards

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't reply earlier: but your result confirms my suspicion, it's just that you use an approximation to integrate a differential equation. The approximation even has a name (Euler method), and the dependency upon step size is known, too (halving the step size decreases the error _per step_ to $1/4,$ approximately). But.... don't you think that's sufficient? That's not even visibile on a 4k display after a few hours, and few are likely to run it that long. It's an impressive visualization of very important ideas.

Comment: -@Professsor Vector . Thanks for your remark, could you tell me please how to proove that error is is decreasing as 1/4 per step when halving step ( **error** $\propto h^2$ ) ? or give me some clues to proove it ? Regards

Comment: That's not difficult, you sum up the differential, i.e. the first term in the Taylor series with the first derivative, and the next one you neglect has order $h^2.$ I guess higher order terms in this transport business get rather hairy.

Comment: -@Professor Vector : actually, in my code, I reproduce the transport of the vector in a geometrically way (by doing rotation transformations and compute tangent vectors); Then, I wanted to compare the numerical results and the theorical values (especially about the values of total differential with its theorical formulas) : I thought that I would obtain better precision on results. You seem to tell that results are relatively accurate, so I think I cannot do more. Thanks